# How to async run a command file in the the commands folder

Tags: discord, discord.js

I wanted to add a kick command to my discord bot, which uses the await function.The only way i know to async run is

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
```

however, I cannot do this in a command file inside the commands folder
My kick command

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "kick",
  description: "kicks a member",
  execute(client, args) {

    if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Invalid Permissions")
    let member = message.mentions.members.first()
    if(!member)
      return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
    if(!member.kickable) 
      return message.reply("I cannot kick this user! Do they have a higher role? Do I have kick permissions?");
    
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
    
    await member.kick(reason)
      .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't kick because of : ${error}`));
    message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been kicked by ${message.author.tag} because: ${reason}`)
    }}
```

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, Im pretty new to coding

Comment: If possible, could you supply some more information about how your commands work. What code is being used to interpret that command in your main file?

Comment: const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "kick",
  description: "kicks a member",
  // vvv THIS LINE CHANGED vvv
  // vvv THIS LINE CHANGED vvv
  // vvv THIS LINE CHANGED vvv
  execute: async (client, args) => {

    if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Invalid Permissions")
    let member = message.mentions.members.first()
    if(!member)
      return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
    if(!member.kickable) 
      return message.reply("I cannot kick this user! Do they have a higher role? Do I have kick permissions?");
    
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
    
    await member.kick(reason)
      .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't kick because of : ${error}`));
    message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been kicked by ${message.author.tag} because: ${reason}`)
    }}
```

Specific Change:
`execute(client, args) {`
becomes
`execute: async (client, args) => {`

Essentially what that does is it says the function is async, vs your code is just declaring execute as a normal (sync) function. Also since I'm not sure if you can declare an async function with normal function syntax, I changed it to ES6 arrow function syntax:
eg. `execute() {}` to `execute: () => {}`
You can read more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: ah yes, I tried to do this, but I didnt know that I was supposed to put the arrow, thank you so much